# highcharts datetime data not working on column type, but working on line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a stacked column chart using highcharts.js with datetime data
It works on line type, but not working on column. The result were flat 100%.

What i need is the chart will appear as stacked column. what do i missed? 
I tried stacked: 'normal' on plotOptions, but still not working.

Please advise, thank you

[image]

My highcharts options:

```
var optionsProcessTime = {
        global: {
                useUTC: false
        },
    title: {
        text: '',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {                
            categories: [],
            labels:{
                formatter: function(){
                    return '#'+this.value;
                }
            }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
                    second: '%H:%M:%S',
                    minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                    hour: '%H:%M:%S'
            },
            labels:{
                format: '{value:%H:%M:%S}'
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
            type: 'datetime',
            formatter: function(){
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',new Date(this.y))
            }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled : false
    },
    plotOptions: {
            series: {
        pointPadding: 0.05,
        groupPadding: 0
    },
        column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
        },
            line: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 2,
                    fillColor: '#ad050b'
                },
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                lineWidth: 1,
            }   
    },
    series: []
}
```

My Json output:

```
[{
    "name":"Checker",
    "data":[86,87,91,92,93,94,99,100,101]},
{
    "name":"Estimate",
    "type":"column",
    "data":[1517018400000,1517014800000,1517014800000,1517018400000,1517017200000,1517015700000,1517013900000,1517013900000,1517013900000]},
{
    "name":"Process",
    "type":"column",
    "data":[1517018400000,1517013666000,1517014800000,1517016664000,1517015107000,1517014984000,1517013604000,1517013900000,1517013900000]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to disable, for debugging only, your definition for `yAxis.labels`. You will see original labels and realize how it works :)

In short, stacking renders each value on top of the previous one, for example: `1517018400000 + 1517018400000 = 3034036800000` so it renders point in 2066 year. And since all columns starts from zero (`0`) the distance is quite big: 136 years. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L4Lgbvvm/45/

Why it works for a line chart then? Simply, `line` type doesn't start at zero as `column` does. You can achieve the same result (**without stacking**) for column too, by setting [`series.threshold`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.threshold) to null: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1s4sqps/

What about `stacking`? I'm not sure how this should work.. it works the same way for columns and lines, compare stackings:

- line: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1s4sqps/1/
- column: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1s4sqps/2/

If you could explain how stacking should be rendered in your opinion, let me know, maybe we can find some solution for it. An image of such stacking would be great.